# Rails: Starting Sidekiq on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq

I'm having a problem getting Sidekiq up and running on my Heroku deployed Rails app. I have my app working fine in development (and on Heroku without Sidekiq).

I created a Procfile with:

```
worker: bundle exec sidekiq
```

If I run `heroku ps`, the only process I see is `web.1`.

Should I see one for 
Sidekiq?

I do get an error:

`Redis::CannotConnectError (Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379)` in my Heroku logs.

UPDATE: Found I probably needed `heroku addons:add redistogo`. Still not working.  I feel I'm missing some basic configuration.

Is there something I need to do to get Redis up and running for my Heroku app?

I've been using Redis/Sidekiq for about a day, so this is new to me.

Thanks!

Greg

Answer (score 65, accepted):

No you do not need any config with Heroku for Sidekiq, just add the **RedisToGo** plugin and you're on.
Do not forget to attribute at least 1 *worker* to your app in your Heroku config.

Here is my default Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec thin start -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c 5 -v
```

Comment: Yeah... it was the missing worker that was the last hangup for me.  Thank you for the response!  As an aside, why do you use 'thin'?  Thanks!

Comment: old project, i'm gonna change for unicorn.
if the answer help you click on the '^' arrow vote ;)
++

Comment: Can you please explain the -c 5 -v options?

Comment: c : concurrency, v: verbose, p: port.
You should read the documentation. really.

Comment: run `bundle exec sidekiq -?` to see a list of options with explanations

Comment: @gdurelle The actual documentation doesn't show this in the deploy section.  The documentation in general is very segmented, and it's easy to miss information.

Comment: I can only access the options help via `bundle exec sidekiq -h` Not sure if anybody has any further references to how to determine concurrency settings.

Comment: @gdurelle what does the `-c 5 -v` do ?

Comment: @tambakoo Question already asked in comments above. This question is quite all maybe it has changed since : c is concurrency and v is verbose.

Comment: for anyone reading this: for rails 6 in 2020 heroku recommends using puma.

Answer (score 51):

It's worth checking if the sidekiq process is really started with this command:

```
heroku ps
```

If there's no worker, then you might need to run this command:

```
heroku ps:scale worker+1
```

It turns out that there's a bug in the web UI in that some team members were not allowed to increase the number of workers from 0 to 1, even though the UI seemed to show that!

Comment: this.  this was the answer to four hours of "why?!?!1!?1?!?!".  thank you.  (in fairness, I also needed to add the "worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c 5 -v", but you know, I did that four hours)

Answer (score 20):

Starting with sidekiq version 3.0 there is an additional step, run `heroku config:set REDIS_PROVIDER=REDISTOGO_URL` in the console.

Here is the process I used for Rails 4:

In the console:

```
heroku addons:create redistogo
heroku config:set REDIS_PROVIDER=REDISTOGO_URL
```

In my `Procfile` I added:

```
worker: bundle exec sidekiq
```

In my `gemfile.rb` I added:

```
gem 'redis'
```

I added the following file, `config/initializers/redis.rb`:

```
uri = ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] || "redis://localhost:6379/"
REDIS = Redis.new(:url => uri)
```

Here is the [link](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment#heroku) to the sidekiq docs.

Answer (score 9):

Complementing gdurelle answer:

You do need some config with Heroku for Sidekiq:

1) Have the Sidekiq and Redis gems installed (in gemfile and bundled), in my case:

Gemfile

```
gem 'redis', '~> 3.1'
gem 'sidekiq', '~> 2.7', '>= 2.7.1'
```

2) Add a worker, if you don't have any workers created locally I suggest you create at least one, just in case, use this:

```
rails g sidekiq:worker Hard # will create app/workers/hard_worker.rb
```

should create this:

app/workers/hard_worker.rb

```
class HardWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform(name, count)
    # do something
  end
end
```

3) Add the Redis add-on (in my case Heroku Redis):

```
heroku addons:create heroku-redis:hobby-dev
```

4) Add your redis.rb file, in my case:

config/initializers/redis.rb

```
$redis = Redis.new(url: ENV["REDIS_URL"])
```

5) Add Procfile or config/sidekiq.yml or both, here are mine:

Procfile

```
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c 1 -q default -q mailers
```

which you can create easier by pasting this in your terminal

```
echo "worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c 1 -q default -q mailers" > Procfile
```

config/sidekiq.yml

```
:concurrency: 1
:queues:
  - [mailers, 7]
  - [default, 5]
```

6) Most important part go [here](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/equitec-app/resources):
[image]
and turn on the switch for your worker, click on the pencil and then turn on the missing switch. Things should be working fine now, have a great day!

Comment: Turning on the worker switch is what did it for me, as I already had the worker defined in my Procfile. THANK YOU!

Comment: I’m glad it helped, have a great day!

Comment: Gosh, I was looking like a mad man why Sidekiq wasn't running and the switch was off all the time. Thanks!

Comment: Always glad to be of help, have a great day, happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're almost there.  It may be that you just need to set REDISTOGO_URL on the [heroku config](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)?

```
heroku config
```

should show you the redistogo value?

If you copy that to REDISTOGO_URL then sidekiq should work?

```
heroku config:add REDISTOGO_URL=<redistogo value>
```

***Edit:*** 
Sidekiq will use any of these currently: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/redis_connection.rb#L29-L33

***Edit2:***
Greg is correct in that you don't need to add the config if you're using RedisToGo.  But if you're using OpenRedis, or other Redis providers, then you need to add REDISTOGO_URL for Sidekiq

Comment: Edit #1 is no longer accurate.

Answer (score 2):

What I found out is that you have to scale process manually like so:

```
heroku ps:scale worker+1
```

Makes no sense since my Procfile said:

```
web: bundle exec....
worker: bundle exec sidekiq
```

...and one would've expectd Heroku to start the worker automatically. In the end I didn't have to scale the web process...

Also, you might have problems with this line: 
    worker: bundle exec sidekiq

Add flags for concurency:

```
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c 5 -v
```

Comment: I've had exactly the same problem with `Heroku Redis` instance. Couldn't turn on the switch on Heroku dashboard, so this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course run sidekiq alongside your current jobs queue.

Our Procfile currently looks like this:

```
web: bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p $PORT
worker:  bundle exec rake jobs:work
sidekiq: bundle exec sidekiq -c 5 -v
```