# How to get Sidekiq workers running on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq

I've set up Sidekiq with my Rails project.  It's running on Heroku with Unicorn.  I've gone through all the configuration steps including setting the proper REDISTOGO_URL ([as this question references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770713/starting-sidekiq-on-heroku)), I've added the following to my after_fork in unicorn.rb:

```
after_fork do |server,worker|
    if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
        ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
        Rails.logger.info('Connected to ActiveRecord')
    end

    Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
        config.redis = { :size => 1 }
    end
end
```

My Procfile is as follows:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
worker: bundle exec sidekiq
```

Right now I call my worker to perform_async and it adds the task to the queue.  In fact in my Sidekiq web interface it says there are 7 items in the queue and it has all of the data there.  Yet there are no workers processing the queue and for the life of me, I can't figure out why.  If I run

```
heroku ps
```

I get the following output:

```
=== web: `bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
web.1: up 2012/12/09 08:04:24 (~ 9m ago)

=== worker: `bundle exec sidekiq`
worker.1: up 2012/12/09 08:04:08 (~ 10m ago)
```

Anybody have any idea what's going on here?

**Update**

Here's the code for my worker class.  Yes, I'm aware that the Oj gem has some issues potentially with sidekiq, but figured I'd give it a shot first.  I'm not getting any error messages at this point (the workers don't even run).

```
require 'addressable/uri'
class DatasiftInteractionsWorker
include Sidekiq::Worker
sidekiq_options queue: "tweets"

def perform( stream_id , interactions )
    interactions = Oj.load(interactions)
    interactions.each{ |interaction|
        if interaction['interaction']['type'] == 'twitter'
            url = interaction['links']['normalized_url'] unless interaction['links']['normalized_url'][0].nil?
            url = interaction['links']['url'] if interaction['links']['normalized_url'][0].nil?
            begin
                puts interaction['links'] if url[0].nil?
                next if url[0].nil?
                host = Addressable::URI.parse(url[0]).host
                host = host.gsub(/^www\.(.*)$/,'\1')
                date_str = Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d')
                REDIS.pipelined do
                    # Add domain to Redis domains Set
                    REDIS.sadd date_str , host
                    # INCR Redis host
                    REDIS.incr( host + date_str )
                end
            rescue
                puts "ERROR: Could not store the following links: " + interaction['links'].to_s
            end
        end
    }
end
end
```

Comment: Do you see anything in your heroku logs with [worker.1] ? something like `heroku logs -t | grep worker.1` (and then perform_async)

Comment: Assuming you are using the free plan, then this means that you have only access to one worker.

Comment: @JesseWolgamott Yes, it's up: 2012-12-09T16:04:08+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2012-12-09T16:04:08+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up

Comment: @JesseWolgamott after running perform_async nothing happens ... It just adds to the queue but the worker never runs

Comment: @NickONeill ok --- would you add the code in your worker class?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott in going through this process, I think I just figured it out ...  since I was using a custom queue name it wasn't loading items in that queue

Comment: thanks @NickONeill, looks like i have the same exact problem. is there a way to pick up items from that specific queue?

Answer (score 6):

My preference is to create a /config/sidekiq.yml file and then use `worker: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml` in your Procfile.

[Here's](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/examples/config.yml) an example sidekiq.yml file

Answer (score 4):

Figured out that if you're using a custom queue, you need to make Sidekiq aware of that queue in the Procfile, as follows:

```
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -q tweets, 1 -q default
```

I'm not quite sure why this is the case since sidekiq is aware of all queues.  I'll post this as an issue on the Sidekiq project.