# How to get Sidekiq working on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

It's my first attempt to get Redis working on Heroku.

I've added one worker dyno (just today, so didn't pay yet), added RedisToGo Nano add-on, tested background jobs on my local machine, and pushed the app to heroku.

```
heroku ps
```

gives

```
=== web: `bundle exec rails server -p $PORT`
web.1: up 2013/03/03 18:26:09 (~ 37m ago)

=== worker: `bundle exec rake jobs:work`
worker.1: crashed 2013/03/03 19:02:15 (~ 1m ago)
```

Sidekiq Web Interface says that one job is enqueued, but zero processed or failed.

I'm guessing it's because my worker dyno is crashed.

Are there any noob mistakes that I don't know about?

(e.g. I need to run some command to start listening to background jobs etc)

`heroku logs --tail` doesn't show any errors, so I don't understand why my worker dyno chashes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I did some research and fixed it like this:

Under app's root directory I created a file called "Procfile" with this content:

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c 5 -v
```

Got this idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770713/starting-sidekiq-on-heroku).

After that it worked ok.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you setup REDIS_PROVIDER:

```
heroku config:set REDIS_PROVIDER=REDISTOGO_URL
```

Sidekiq's GitHub page also has instruction. Click [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment)