# Why is my email not being delivered in my Ruby on Rails 5 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rails app on Heroku which can send emails. I added a new feature to send email for a notification.
I get this in Heroku logs but no emails are sent.

```
2016-07-29T19:57:58.895499+00:00 app[web.1]: [ActiveJob] [NotificationBroadcastJob] [40c7b651-3c5d-4308-b8b5-49a142d2930f]   Rendered notifications_mailer/new_message.html.erb (226.4ms)
2016-07-29T19:57:58.895630+00:00 app[web.1]: [ActiveJob] [NotificationBroadcastJob] [40c7b651-3c5d-4308-b8b5-49a142d2930f] NotificationsMailer#new_message: processed outbound mail in 246.0ms
2016-07-29T19:57:58.895741+00:00 app[web.1]: [ActiveJob] [NotificationBroadcastJob] [40c7b651-3c5d-4308-b8b5-49a142d2930f] Performed NotificationBroadcastJob from Async(default) in 377.85ms
```

This is notifications_mailer ruby file app/mailers/notifications_mailer.rb

```
class NotificationsMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def new_message(message)
    @message = message
    mail(to: message.receiver.email, subject: 'You have a new message')
  end  
end
```

This is how I call the new_message action in app/jobs/notifications_broadcast_job.rb

```
class NotificationBroadcastJob < ApplicationJob
.
.
    NotificationsMailer.new_message(personal_message).deliver_now
```

I use Sendgrid addon and this is from production.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  host = 'www.abcdef.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'www.abcdef.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

This is my development.rb

```
  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
  host = 'rails-tutorial-suai.c9.io'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
```

I don't have worker dynos. This is my Procfile.

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

Can anyone kindly help? Thanks

Comment: Have you configured sendgrid or some other email service?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes. I updated the questions with those settings.

Comment: Do you have a worker dyno spun up? What is in your procfile?

Comment: @M00B I don't have worker dynos. This is my Procfile.

web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb

Answer (score 1):

Your call site of `NotificationsMailer` is in `class NotificationBroadcastJob < ApplicationJob`. That means that you are using [ActiveJob](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html). From the [Mailer docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html):

> Active Job's default behavior is to execute jobs via the :async
>   adapter. So, you can use deliver_later now to send emails
>   asynchronously. Active Job's default adapter runs jobs with an
>   in-process thread pool. It's well-suited for the development/test
>   environments, since it doesn't require any external infrastructure,
>   but it's a poor fit for production since it drops pending jobs on
>   restart. If you need a persistent backend, you will need to use an
>   Active Job adapter that has a persistent backend (Sidekiq, Resque,
>   etc).

So in development it will work without a Job backend like Sidekiq/Resque. Assuming you have something like that set up on Heroku, you will need to have at least one worker dyno spun up and a worker process registered in your Procfile.

Here are the [docs on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing), but the gist is: you will need [Redis](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-redis), a queue backend like [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/), a worker process registered in your Procfile (e.g. `worker: bundle exec sidekiq -q default`), and a worker process spun up on Heroku (e.g. `$ heroku ps:scale web=1 worker=1`).

This also assumes you have provisioned the sendgrid addon on your Heroku app and added the required Config Vars.

[A similar SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13948786/1254263).