# Sidekiq job enqueued but not processing on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, sidekiq

Rails 5.2
redis 4.0.1
sidekiq 5.1.3

RedisToGo on Heroku

Proc File:

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -e production -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

sidekiq.yml

```
development:
  :concurrency: 5
production:
  :concurrency: 6
:queues:
  - default
```

config/initialize/sidekiq.rb

```
if Rails.env.production?

  Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { url: ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'] || ENV['REDIS_URL'], size: 1 }
  end

  Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    pool_size = ENV['SIDEKIQ_DB_POOL'] || (Sidekiq.options[:concurrency] + 2)
    config.redis = { url: ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'] || ENV['REDIS_URL'], size: pool_size }

    Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
      Rails.logger.info("DB Connection Pool size for Sidekiq Server before disconnect is: #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.pool.instance_variable_get('@size')}")
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!

      ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
        db_config = Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
        db_config['reaping_frequency'] = ENV['DATABASE_REAP_FREQ'] || 10 # seconds
        db_config['pool'] = pool_size
        ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(db_config)
        Rails.logger.info("DB Connection Pool size for Sidekiq Server is now: #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.pool.instance_variable_get('@size')}")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

[image]

I have no idea why the job is stuck in the queue. The job works on my local in development.

Any assistance appreciated.

Update!
As per the comment here is the output of heroku ps:

```
=== web (Free): bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb (1)
web.1: up 2018/06/15 18:49:56 +0700 (~ 5s ago)

=== worker (Free): bundle exec sidekiq -q default (1)
worker.1: crashed 2018/06/15 18:49:51 +0700 (~ 10s ago)
```

Seems a worker crashed for some reason.

Heroku logs:

```
2018-06-15T11:56:00.301716+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] Puma starting in cluster mode...
2018-06-15T11:56:00.301740+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Version 3.11.2 (ruby 2.4.1-p111), codename: Love Song
2018-06-15T11:56:00.301760+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2018-06-15T11:56:00.301794+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Environment: production
2018-06-15T11:56:00.301801+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Process workers: 2
2018-06-15T11:56:00.301838+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Preloading application
2018-06-15T11:56:01.249511+00:00 app[worker.1]: DB Connection Pool size for Sidekiq Server before disconnect is: 5
2018-06-15T11:56:01.252654+00:00 app[worker.1]: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
2018-06-15T11:56:01.252657+00:00 app[worker.1]: Is the server running locally and accepting
2018-06-15T11:56:01.252659+00:00 app[worker.1]: connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Comment: Can you run `heroku ps` to check workers? Maybe helpful this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770713/rails-starting-sidekiq-on-heroku

Comment: It seems like Sidekiq can read your Redis DB, as it has a job enqueued. Ensure that you have at least 1 dyno worker. Also, restart the servers.

Comment: restarted servers and again worker crashes

Comment: Yes `heroku restart` in your project directory

Comment: Increase pool in your DB settings to 25 or 50.

Comment: `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql` add postgres to your heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking with tech support at Heroku it turns out that I needed to change the way I had my db yaml file coded.

I changed it to the following:

```
production:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

That seem to solve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Install Heroku Postgres as an addon and then add the environment variables to your project and everything should work fine. - https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql